# Using jinja2 and python 3, get undefined variable error

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using Jinja 2 and Python 3.

I'm trying to include a partial view in my code like this:

```
{% include partials/menu.html %}
```

Resulting in this error:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'partials' is undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hint: you will not have much fun here without good knowledge of English. Consider looking for forums in your language.

Comment: Just telling you: you can call yourself happy. You had 3, 4 people editing your almost un-readable question. At other times of the day, such a question would have -10 downvotes by now; would be closed in 3 minutes, and deleted in 10 minutes.

Comment: I are so very sorry GhostCat pleese forgive

Comment: No need to feel sorry. You did nothing wrong. I understand your desire to post here. I am just telling you: people are not always that friendly when they are confronted with "not so great" input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the double quote around your path in your include statement:

```
{% include "partials/menu.html" %}
```

Comment: @TychkinNikitovich You are welcome. Just like GhostCat mentioned, try to brush up on your English a bit.